# How can i get data based on condition from within a group by

Tags: sql-server

Consider the following tables

### Log (LOG)

Id, CorrId, FlowId, FlowName, AppId, ReqTimestamp, Source, Target, Step, CustomField

### Message (MESSAGE)

Id, Url, Method, Headers, MsgBlob, CreatedDatetime

### LinkedLogs (LOG_LOGS)

Id, CorrId, LinkedCorId

### Create table and insert statements

```sql
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LOG](
        [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [CORRELATION_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
        [ERROR_CODE] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
        [FLOW_ID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [APPLICATION_ID] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
        [LOG_LEVEL] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
        [LOG_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [EVENT_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [FLOW_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [PROCESS] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
        [REQUEST_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [SOURCE] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
        [TARGET] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
        [STEP] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [LOG_SEQUENCE] [int] NOT NULL,
        [CREATED_DATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [CUSTOM_FIELD] [nvarchar](60) NULL)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MESSAGE](
        [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [URL] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
        [METHOD] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
        [MSGBLOB] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [HEADERS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [CREATED_DATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LOG_LOGS](
        [CorrelationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [LinkedCorrelationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [CreatedDatetime] [datetime] NULL)

    --Log

    INSERT [dbo].[LOG]
        ([ID], [CORRELATION_ID], [ERROR_CODE], [FLOW_ID], [APPLICATION_ID], [LOG_LEVEL], [LOG_TIMESTAMP], [EVENT_ID], [FLOW_NAME], [PROCESS], [REQUEST_TIMESTAMP], [SOURCE], [TARGET], [STEP], [DESCRIPTION], [LOG_SEQUENCE], [CREATED_DATETIME], [CUSTOM_FIELD])
    VALUES
        ('C56BBFBE-5308-4242-ACD0-383F016C0AD1', '8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', 'NULL', 'TRIGGER', 'appIdString', 'DEBUG', '2019-04-26 14:08:23.660', 'C0F40CA0-682C-11E9-AB6D-0298370A6804', 'trigger', 'imp-trigger', '2019-04-26 14:08:23.660', 'SomeSource', 'SomeTarget', 'START', 'Some description', '1', '2019-04-26 14:08:24.677', 'NULL');
    INSERT [dbo].[LOG]
        ([ID], [CORRELATION_ID], [ERROR_CODE], [FLOW_ID], [APPLICATION_ID], [LOG_LEVEL], [LOG_TIMESTAMP], [EVENT_ID], [FLOW_NAME], [PROCESS], [REQUEST_TIMESTAMP], [SOURCE], [TARGET], [STEP], [DESCRIPTION], [LOG_SEQUENCE], [CREATED_DATETIME], [CUSTOM_FIELD])
    VALUES
        ('273F4E0A-CA7A-40B5-AF54-F2A53A776541', '8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', 'NULL', 'TRIGGER', 'appIdString', 'DEBUG', '2019-04-26 14:08:25.693', 'C0F40CA0-682C-11E9-AB6D-0298370A6804', 'trigger-melto', 'imp-trigger', '2019-04-26 14:08:23.660', 'SomeSource', 'SomeTarget', 'OUTBOUND', 'Some description', '4', '2019-04-26 14:08:29.110', 'NULL');
    INSERT [dbo].[LOG]
        ([ID], [CORRELATION_ID], [ERROR_CODE], [FLOW_ID], [APPLICATION_ID], [LOG_LEVEL], [LOG_TIMESTAMP], [EVENT_ID], [FLOW_NAME], [PROCESS], [REQUEST_TIMESTAMP], [SOURCE], [TARGET], [STEP], [DESCRIPTION], [LOG_SEQUENCE], [CREATED_DATETIME], [CUSTOM_FIELD])
    VALUES
        ('7AF12EBE-93AC-443F-82CD-9079C2851C9E', '8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', 'NULL', 'TRIGGER', 'appIdString', 'DEBUG', '2019-04-26 14:08:25.690', 'C0F40CA0-682C-11E9-AB6D-0298370A6804', 'trigger-melto', 'imp-trigger', '2019-04-26 14:08:23.660', 'SomeSource', 'SomeTarget', 'INBOUND', 'Some description', '3', '2019-04-26 14:08:29.270', 'NULL');
    INSERT [dbo].[LOG]
        ([ID], [CORRELATION_ID], [ERROR_CODE], [FLOW_ID], [APPLICATION_ID], [LOG_LEVEL], [LOG_TIMESTAMP], [EVENT_ID], [FLOW_NAME], [PROCESS], [REQUEST_TIMESTAMP], [SOURCE], [TARGET], [STEP], [DESCRIPTION], [LOG_SEQUENCE], [CREATED_DATETIME], [CUSTOM_FIELD])
    VALUES
        ('E0F5018E-8876-4929-828B-E1DB26CF7F30', '8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', 'NULL', 'TRIGGER', 'appIdString', 'DEBUG', '2019-04-26 14:08:25.477', 'C0F40CA0-682C-11E9-AB6D-0298370A6804', 'trigger-melto', 'imp-trigger', '2019-04-26 14:08:23.660', 'SomeSource', 'SomeTarget', 'OUTBOUND', 'Some description', '2', '2019-04-26 14:08:29.447', 'NULL');
    INSERT [dbo].[LOG]
        ([ID], [CORRELATION_ID], [ERROR_CODE], [FLOW_ID], [APPLICATION_ID], [LOG_LEVEL], [LOG_TIMESTAMP], [EVENT_ID], [FLOW_NAME], [PROCESS], [REQUEST_TIMESTAMP], [SOURCE], [TARGET], [STEP], [DESCRIPTION], [LOG_SEQUENCE], [CREATED_DATETIME], [CUSTOM_FIELD])
    VALUES
        ('8B7A0A86-14D8-4E72-8047-21A73ECF6157', '8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', '504', 'TRIGGER', 'appIdString', 'DEBUG', '2019-04-26 14:08:35.833', 'C0F40CA0-682C-11E9-AB6D-0298370A6804', 'trigger-melto', 'imp-trigger', '2019-04-26 14:08:23.660', 'SomeSource', 'SomeTarget', 'ERROR', 'Some description', '5', '2019-04-26 14:08:37.500', 'NULL');

    -- Message

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MESSAGE]
        ([ID] ,[URL] ,[METHOD] ,[MSGBLOB] ,[HEADERS] ,[CREATED_DATETIME])
    VALUES
        ('C56BBFBE-5308-4242-ACD0-383F016C0AD1', 'https://localhost:1234/api/trigger', 'POST', 'U29tZSBtZXNzYWdlIGJsb2IgdG8gZGVjb2Rl', '{"Content-Type":"application/xml"}', '2019-04-26 14:08:25.577');
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MESSAGE]
        ([ID] ,[URL] ,[METHOD] ,[MSGBLOB] ,[HEADERS] ,[CREATED_DATETIME])
    VALUES
        ('273F4E0A-CA7A-40B5-AF54-F2A53A776541', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'U29tZSBtZXNzYWdlIGJsb2IgdG8gZGVjb2Rl', 'null', '2019-04-26 14:08:29.813');
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MESSAGE]
        ([ID] ,[URL] ,[METHOD] ,[MSGBLOB] ,[HEADERS] ,[CREATED_DATETIME])
    VALUES
        ('E0F5018E-8876-4929-828B-E1DB26CF7F30', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'U29tZSBtZXNzYWdlIGJsb2IgdG8gZGVjb2Rl', 'null', '2019-04-26 14:08:29.613');
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MESSAGE]
        ([ID] ,[URL] ,[METHOD] ,[MSGBLOB] ,[HEADERS] ,[CREATED_DATETIME])
    VALUES
        ('8B7A0A86-14D8-4E72-8047-21A73ECF6157', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'U29tZSBtZXNzYWdlIGJsb2IgdG8gZGVjb2Rl', 'null', '2019-04-26 14:08:37.817');

    -- Log_Logs

    INSERT [dbo].[LOG_LOGS]
        ([CorrelationId], [LinkedCorrelationId], [CreatedDatetime])
    VALUES
        ('8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', '972039B5-346B-4BC8-AE9B-2A45D51DA310', '2019-06-19 10:54:33.023');
    INSERT [dbo].[LOG_LOGS]
        ([CorrelationId], [LinkedCorrelationId], [CreatedDatetime])
    VALUES
        ('8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', '972039B5-346B-4BC8-AE9B-2A45D51DA310', '2019-06-19 10:54:33.023');
    INSERT [dbo].[LOG_LOGS]
        ([CorrelationId], [LinkedCorrelationId], [CreatedDatetime])
    VALUES
        ('8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', '972039B5-346B-4BC8-AE9B-2A45D51DA310', '2019-06-19 10:54:33.023');
    INSERT [dbo].[LOG_LOGS]
        ([CorrelationId], [LinkedCorrelationId], [CreatedDatetime])
    VALUES
        ('8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', '972039B5-346B-4BC8-AE9B-2A45D51DA310', '2019-06-19 10:54:33.023');
    INSERT [dbo].[LOG_LOGS]
        ([CorrelationId], [LinkedCorrelationId], [CreatedDatetime])
    VALUES
        ('8C519F41-1F06-41E5-9647-25554315E1C7', '972039B5-346B-4BC8-AE9B-2A45D51DA310', '2019-06-19 10:54:33.023');
```

### What i need as a result (paged by 10,20 or 50 records)

- Grouped by the Log.CorrId
- Log.ReqTimestamp (should be the same for all Log.CorId)
- Log.Source (should be the same for all Log.CorId)
- Log.Target (should be the same for all Log.CorId)
- **Log.FlowName (not the same for all Log.CorId: so where Log.Step =
  'OUTBOUND', if not available Log.Step = 'END', if not available any
  is ok)**
- CanResubmit: SUM(case when l.STEP = 'START' and DATALENGTH(m.MSGBLOB) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
- HasError: SUM(case when l.STEP = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 end)
- HasEnd: SUM(case when l.STEP = 'END' then 1 else 0 end)
- HasLinkedLog

This is what i have so far.

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchFlowCorrelationIds]
        @FlowIdList AS dbo.FlowIdList READONLY,
        @CorrelationIdList AS dbo.CorrelationIdList READONLY,
        @FlowName nvarchar(50) = null,
        @Source nvarchar(256) = null,
        @Target nvarchar(256) = null,
        @ApplicationId nvarchar(35) = null,
        @CustomField nvarchar(60) = null,
        @Step nvarchar(50) = null,
        @DateFrom datetime = null,
        @DateTo datetime = null,
        @SortField nvarchar(50) = 'RequestTimestamp',
        @SortOrder nvarchar(4) = null,
        @Take int = 10,
        @Skip int = 0
    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @DateBoundaryFrom int = 1;
    DECLARE @DateBoundaryTo int = 13;

    SELECT result.CORRELATION_ID as CorrelationId
        ,   result.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP as RequestTimestamp
        ,   result.FLOW_NAME as FlowName
        ,   result.SOURCE as Source
        ,   result.TARGET as Target
        ,   result.CanResubmit
        ,   result.HasError
        ,   result.HasEnd
        ,   result.LinkedCorrelationId as LinkedCorrelationId

    FROM 
        (SELECT  lastLogged.CORRELATION_ID
                , lastLogged.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP
                , lastLogged.SOURCE
                , lastLogged.TARGET
                , lastLogged.FLOW_NAME
                , l2.CanResubmit as CanResubmit
                , l2.HasError as HasError
                , l2.HasEnd as HasEnd
                , ll.LinkedCorrelationId
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lastLogged.CORRELATION_ID ORDER BY lastLogged.LOG_TIMESTAMP DESC) as dest_rank
        FROM LOG as lastLogged

        INNER JOIN (
            select CORRELATION_ID
                ,   SUM(case when l.STEP = 'START' and DATALENGTH(m.MSGBLOB) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as CanResubmit
                ,   SUM(case when l.STEP = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 end) as HasError
                ,   SUM(case when l.STEP = 'END' then 1 else 0 end) as HasEnd
            from LOG l
            left join MESSAGE m on l.ID = m.ID
            Where l.CREATED_DATETIME >= ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY, -@DateBoundaryFrom, @DateFrom), l.CREATED_DATETIME)
            AND l.CREATED_DATETIME <= ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY, @DateBoundaryTo, @DateTo), l.CREATED_DATETIME)
            group by l.CORRELATION_ID

        ) as l2 on lastLogged.CORRELATION_ID = l2.CORRELATION_ID

        LEFT JOIN LOG_LOGS ll on lastLogged.CORRELATION_ID = ll.CorrelationId

        WHERE 
            lastLogged.CREATED_DATETIME >= ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY, -@DateBoundaryFrom, @DateFrom), lastLogged.CREATED_DATETIME)
            AND lastLogged.CREATED_DATETIME <= ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY, @DateBoundaryTo, @DateTo), lastLogged.CREATED_DATETIME)
            AND lastLogged.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP >= ISNULL(@DateFrom, lastLogged.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP)
            AND lastLogged.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP <= ISNULL(@DateTo, lastLogged.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP)
            AND (lastLogged.FLOW_ID in (SELECT Flow_Id FROM @FlowIdList) OR NOT EXISTS (select 1 from @FlowIdList))
            AND (lastLogged.CORRELATION_ID in (SELECT ID FROM @CorrelationIdList) OR NOT EXISTS (select 1 from @CorrelationIdList))
            AND lastLogged.FLOW_NAME = ISNULL(@FlowName, lastLogged.FLOW_NAME)
            AND lastLogged.SOURCE = ISNULL(@Source, lastLogged.SOURCE)
            AND lastLogged.TARGET = ISNULL(@Target, lastLogged.TARGET)
            AND lastLogged.APPLICATION_ID = ISNULL(@ApplicationId, lastLogged.APPLICATION_ID)
            AND lastLogged.STEP = ISNULL(@Step, lastLogged.STEP)        
            AND (lastLogged.CUSTOM_FIELD = @CustomField OR @CustomField IS NULL)
        ) AS result

    WHERE result.dest_rank = 1

    ORDER BY 
    -- ASCENDING
        CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as date)
            WHEN @SortField = 'RequestTimestamp' then result.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP
        end ASC
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as uniqueidentifier)
            WHEN @SortField = 'CorrelationId' then result.CORRELATION_ID
        end ASC
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'ASC' then ''
            WHEN @SortField = 'FlowName' then result.FLOW_NAME
        end ASC
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'ASC' then ''
            WHEN @SortField = 'Source' then result.SOURCE
        end ASC
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'ASC' then ''
            WHEN @SortField = 'Target' then result.TARGET
        end ASC

    -- DESCENDING
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as date)
            WHEN @SortField = 'RequestTimestamp' then result.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP
        end DESC
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as uniqueidentifier)
            WHEN @SortField = 'CorrelationId' then result.CORRELATION_ID
        end DESC
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'DESC' then ''
            WHEN @SortField = 'FlowName' then result.FLOW_NAME
        end DESC
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'DESC' then ''
            WHEN @SortField = 'Source' then result.SOURCE
        end DESC
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @SortOrder <> 'DESC' then ''
            WHEN @SortField = 'Target' then result.TARGET
        end DESC

    OFFSET @skip ROWS FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY
```

### Question

Now the question is how do i get that FlowName in there based on the following conditions:

- where Log.Step = 'OUTBOUND', if not available Log.Step = 'END', if not available any is ok)

(if there are any performance improvements tips, they are always welcome, because this one takes like 8 or more seconds on 7ml records)

Comment: This is a type of catch all query and the performance can tank pretty quickly. See [this article](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) from Gail Shaw and her [follow up](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/revisiting-catch-all-queries). Also that sp_ prefix is no win.Either choose a different prefix or even better no prefix at all. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/revisiting-catch-all-queries For the question at hand...it looks like FlowName is a column in the query already.

Comment: Thanks for the articles, they look interesting at first sight. i'll read them tomorrow when i have more time. I've updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: What would really help is table definitions (create table statements) and sample data (insert statements).

Comment: I've read the articles and they really helped alot with the perfomance. Most times it's half the time of what it used to take. So big thanks for bringing that up! I've also added the create table and insert statements.